# Vue.js if else in view

Tags: if-statement, view, vue.js

Is it possible to have an if / else statement which does not render any html in a view similar to knockout:

```
<!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere -->
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> but it needs to be on an element

Yes, but if `v-if` conditional is false, it's not added to DOM tree.

HTML

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
new Vue({
    el: "#main",
    template: '<div v-if="name"><span v-text="name"></span></div>',
    data: {
//        name: "bob"
    } 
});

console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
// <div id="main"><!--vue-if--></div>
```

Still not good for you?

Answer (score 9):

I know the question was already answered, but thought I would pass along something I use, now that I am writing sites with Vue (which I love.)  I am a fan of Knockout and have many sites written in it using the:

```
<!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere -->
```

You could do a similar thing in Vue like this:

```
<template v-if="someExpressionGoesHere">
  <p>Expression is True</p>
</template>
<template v-else>
  <p>Expression is False</p>
</template>
```

The `template`s will not render anything to the page.  The resulting html will be a single `p` of the 'Expression is xxx'.

I think it is a bit more clear of what the intent of the code is here than the actual answer to this post IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use this way to write if else condition in vue.js

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p v-if="someConditionHere">Condition True</p>
    <p v-else>Condition False</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This feels like the most common use-case example people want